# Find pairs of numbers in a list that add up to 10

Tags: python

Given a list of numbers, I would like to find all pairs of numbers that add up to 10.

How can I write a function to do this in Python?

Comment: It is hard to say what do you need. Can you give some examples of input and output?

Answer (score 5):

Just store the difference from 10 in a set:

```
def find(arr, total):
    d = set()
    for e in arr:
        if e in d:
            print total-e, e
            break
        d.add(total-e)

s = [1,5,3,10,11,7,2]
find(s, 10)
```

Comment: An excellent little example in roughly three minutes. I'm impressed. :)

Comment: You should use a `set` instead of a `dict` for testing membership.

Comment: Nice that this is `O(n)`. Storing the complements and seeing when they are found is a nice approach.

Comment: You have a bug: you wrote `for e in s`, but you meant `for e in arr`

Answer (score 3):

```
l = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[(x,y) for x in l for y in l if x+y==10]
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty old, but I thought I would contribute my own answer because both of the provided solutions at time of writing have subtle errors: one only provides one pair of numbers that adds up to 10; the other re-uses numbers (ex., even though 5 is only in the list once, (5, 5) gets listed as a solution in addition to repeating the pairs).

Using the itertools library, you can do the following:

```
from itertools import combinations

def pair_sums(arr, expected=10):
     return [x for x in combinations(arr, 2) if sum(x) == expected]

arr1 = [2, 4, 5, 6, 8]
pair_sums(arr1)  # returns [(2, 8), (4, 6)]

arr2 = [2, 5, 7, 5, 9, 3]
pair_sums(arr2)  # returns [(5, 5), (7, 3)]
```